# Is it possible to run different ros distributions and still communicate with each other in a distributed computing setup?

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, master, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have two computers connected to the same network and if computer A has ROS Indigo installed and if computer B has ROS Kinetic installed, can I run the master in computer A and export the ROS_MASTER_URI to the one of computer A in Computer B to communicate with the master?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262983/is-it-possible-to-run-different-ros-distributions-and-still-communicate-with-each-other-in-a-distributed-computing-setup?/) by [SubMarIN](https://answers.ros.org/users/30591/submarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using such a setup (ROS Indigo on a robot and ROS Kinetic on a laptop) and it works perfectly. On my laptop I just had to export the following variables:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://IP.OF.RO.BOT:11311
export ROS_IP=IP.OF.LAP.TOP
```

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SubMarIN](https://answers.ros.org/users/30591/submarin/) on 2017-06-01**:
Thanks! It's working for me now! Just that I had to export the ROS_IP in each of the computers.

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-06-01**:
Great! If my answer helped you, please click on the gray checkmark on the left to confirm, that the answer was correct.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-02**:
Just a note: this only works in case message definitions have not changed between ROS releases. For messages in the 'core' (ie: `std_msgs`, `sensor_msgs` and similar) that is often the case, but for others it may not be true. You'll get MD5 mismatch errors in case things are not compatible anymore.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-06-08**:
What is the best way to check if this has happened? For example if I wanted a Indigo and Kinetic distro to talk to each other?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-09**:
Not sure it's the best way, but `rosmg md5 $pkg/$msg` will calculate the md5 for you. You could then compare versions in different releases.

Note that you'll automatically get warnings about mismatched MD5s when trying to setup comms though. It's not like things silently fail or ignore it.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-06-09**:
So an example would be `rosmsg md5 $geometry_msgs/Twist`? I'm obviously not using the correct syntax because I get invalid type error messages

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-10**:
No. Use this:

```
rosmsg md5 geometry_msgs/Twist
```